# Making a model undeletable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, ruby-on-rails-4.2

What is the proper way to ensure nobody can delete a model record in Rails through either a console or through some controller that tries to call `model.destroy`? Or even through trying to destroy an object that has `dependent: :destroy` set on the relationship to this undeletable model.

This should never work:

```
User.first.destroy
```

I never want certain models to go missing under any circumstances (aside from, of course, going directly to the database or altering the Ruby code).

Comment: You can always override `destroy` method in this model.

Comment: @MarekLipka - is that the proper way to deal with this? There's no other way to destroy a model record?

Comment: You might need to watch out for `delete` too : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-delete

Comment: There's always other way to destroy a model record from DB. You can also override public `delete` method, but you still can destroy your record, with `delete_all` for example, or you can call private `destroy_row` method etc.

Comment: Also you can use before_desrtoy callback

Comment: It might be easier to handle this at the database level, e.g. setting up a user without `DELETE` privilege or using a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger in MySQL.

Answer (score 5):

IMO you should assign a `before_destroy` callback that raises an error.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :nope

  private

  def nope
    raise "nope!" if (id == 1)
  end
end
```

If raising an error is unacceptable (in case it halts other operations), you'd have to define your own `destroy`:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def destroy
    super if should_destroy?
  end

  def should_destroy?
    id != 1
  end
end
```

The `before_destroy` will intercept `destroy_all` too.

But the following will help in intercepting `destroy_all` more explicitly:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  class ActiveRecord_Relation
    def destroy_all
      where(id: 1).exists? ? raise("nope!") : super
    end
  end
end

Model.where(id: 1).destroy_all #=> nope! (nothing gets destroyed)
Model.where(id: [1, 2]).destroy_all #=> nope! (nothing gets destroyed)
Model.where(id: 2).destroy_all #=> destruction!!! carnage! HAVOC!
```

And an error-free implementation:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  class ActiveRecord_Relation
    def destroy_all
      err_id = 1
      return super unless where(id: err_id).exists?

      ids = pluck(:id) - [err_id]
      where(id: ids).destroy_all
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You don't have to override `destroy_all` if you already overrode `destroy`. If you return falsy value from `before_destroy`, it would also prevent model from destroying.

Comment: Seems like `before_destroy` throwing an exception is the way to go. The `User.first.destroy` was just an example. I don't want ***any*** `User`s being destroyed, doesn't matter if they're the first or the last.